# Why is this javascript showing negative numbers with getTime function?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, date, gettime

I can't figure it out, hope there is a simple solution but I can't see where is this script failing. This script is a part from a wp plugin, but where it fails there is no wp code.

what it does is count to an end date and print it on screen. The line:

amount = (dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5);

is showing a negative number, so It's impossible, future date is "2014-10-23 23:00:00" and the current date and time in my country is "2014-10-23 20:00:00" cannot be < 0 if dateFuture - dateNow. Code fails when is the actual date (2014-10-23) but no the hour. i.e. the actual day always shows Day: 0,  Hour: 0, Mins: 0, Secs: 0. It's working properly if the day is a future day.

Thanks a lot for your help and time in advance.

```
function countdown_shortcode_handler( $args, $content = null ){
$dateEnd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now +3 hours"));
$theme = "default";
$tz = false; //"America/Los_Angeles";

if(isset($args["date"])){ $dateEnd = $args["date"]; }
if(isset($args["theme"])){ $theme = $args["theme"]; }
if(isset($args["timezone"])){ $tz = $args["timezone"]; }

ob_start();
if($tz){
    $oldtz = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($tz); // Change locale
}

$strTime = strtotime($dateEnd);
$randID = md5(rand(9000, 10000));
?>
<link href="<?php print plugins_url('countdown/theme/' . $theme . '/style.css') ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="<?php print $randID ?>" class="countdown"><?php print date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", $strTime) ?></div>

<script>
var dateFuture = new Date(<?php print date("Y", $strTime) ?>,<?php print (date("m", $strTime)-1) ?>,<?php print date("d", $strTime) ?>,<?php print date("h", $strTime) ?>,<?php print date("i", $strTime) ?>,<?php print date("s", $strTime) ?>);

function count<?php print $randID ?>timer(){
dateNow = new Date();
amount = (dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5);
document.write(amount);
delete dateNow;
if(amount < 0){
    jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .days .number").html("0");
    jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .hour .number").html("0");
    jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .mins .number").html("0");
    jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .secs .number").html("0");
}else{
    days = 0;
    hours = 0;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    amount = Math.floor(amount / 1000);
    days = Math.floor(amount / 86400);
    amount = amount % 86400;
    hours = Math.floor(amount / 3600);
    amount = amount % 3600;
    mins = Math.floor(amount / 60);
    amount = amount % 60;
    secs = Math.floor(amount);
    if(jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .days .number").html()!=days){
        jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .days .number").html(days);
    }
    if(jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .hour .number").html()!=hours){
        jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .hour .number").html(hours);
    }
    if(jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .mins .number").html()!=mins){
        jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .mins .number").html(mins);
    }
    if(jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .secs .number").html()!=secs){
        jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .secs .number").html(secs);
    }

    if(days==0){ jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?> .days").hide(); }

    setTimeout("count<?php print $randID ?>timer()", 1000);
}
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var holder_stuff = '<span class="number"></span><span class="over"></span><span class="title"></span>';
var holder_days = jQuery("<span>").addClass("days").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
var holder_hour = jQuery("<span>").addClass("hour").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
var holder_mins = jQuery("<span>").addClass("mins").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
var holder_secs = jQuery("<span>").addClass("secs").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
jQuery("#<?php print $randID ?>").html("").append(holder_days).append(holder_hour).append(holder_mins).append(holder_secs);
count<?php print $randID ?>timer();
});
</script>
<?php
if($tz){
    date_default_timezone_set($oldtz); // Restore current time
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('countdown', 'countdown_shortcode_handler');

function countdown_wp_enqueue_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'countdown_wp_enqueue_scripts');

?>
```

Generated Javascript:

```
<div id="951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498" class="countdown">Thursday 23rd of October 2014 11:00:00 PM</div>

<script>
var dateFuture = new Date(2014,9,23,11,00,00);

function count951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498timer(){
dateNow = new Date();
amount = (dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5);

delete dateNow;
if(amount < 0){
    jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .days .number").html("0");
    jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .hour .number").html("0");
    jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .mins .number").html("0");
    jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .secs .number").html("0");
}else{
    days = 0;
    hours = 0;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    amount = Math.floor(amount / 1000);
    days = Math.floor(amount / 86400);
    amount = amount % 86400;
    hours = Math.floor(amount / 3600);
    amount = amount % 3600;
    mins = Math.floor(amount / 60);
    amount = amount % 60;
    secs = Math.floor(amount);
    if(jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .days .number").html()!=days){
        jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .days .number").html(days);
    }
    if(jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .hour .number").html()!=hours){
        jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .hour .number").html(hours);
    }
    if(jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .mins .number").html()!=mins){
        jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .mins .number").html(mins);
    }
    if(jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .secs .number").html()!=secs){
        jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .secs .number").html(secs);
    }

    if(days==0){ jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498 .days").hide(); }

    setTimeout("count951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498timer()", 1000);
}
 }
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var holder_stuff = '<span class="number"></span><span class="over"></span><span class="title"></span>';
var holder_days = jQuery("<span>").addClass("days").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
var holder_hour = jQuery("<span>").addClass("hour").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
var holder_mins = jQuery("<span>").addClass("mins").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
var holder_secs = jQuery("<span>").addClass("secs").addClass("item").html(holder_stuff);
jQuery("#951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498").html("").append(holder_days).append(holder_hour).append(holder_mins).append(holder_secs);
count951124d4a093eeae83d9726a20295498timer();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your dateFuture actually is in the future?

Comment: Forget the PHP, go to View Source and show us the JavaScript that you're generating. We have no idea what the php date is, etc.

Comment: Yes Mark Baker, It's soo strange. The dateFuture is "2014-10-23 23:00:00". The current date and time in my country is "2014-10-23 20:00:00".

Comment: Looking at your code `var dateFuture = new Date(2014,9,23,11,00,00);` clearly shows "2014-09-23 11:00:00" which is a month ago...

Comment: OK, so in your generated JavaScript, the date is: `var dateFuture = new Date(2014,9,23,11,00,00);` So, 1100 hours. The current date and time locally for you isi 2000 hours. So, it's not in the future.

Comment: @Lochemage, no. Month is 0 based.

Comment: Hour 11 is not 11 pm.

Comment: ah, makes more sense then... but 11:00:00 still seems to be past tense if his time right now is 20:00:00.

Comment: Omg, It's so confusing. The shortcode I'm using is: [countdown date="2014-10-23 23:00:00"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
var dateFuture = new Date(<?php print date("Y", $strTime) ?>,<?php print (date("m", $strTime)-1) ?>,<?php print date("d", $strTime) ?>,<?php print date("h", $strTime) ?>,<?php print date("i", $strTime) ?>,<?php print date("s", $strTime) ?>);
```

You want don't want

```
<?php print date("h", $strTime) ?>
```

You want

```
<?php print date("H", $strTime) ?>
```

In other words you want 0-23 hours, not the 1-12 hours.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You are the man, aquinas!! I spent all day with this!!! I knew it was something simple!! I'm so sorry. Too many hours programming...

Thanks for everything guys!